# centred list but broken down to 3 items per line

Tags: html, css, list, centering, word-wrap

I have a list of items, each item contains various words of various lengths. This list is centred to the page. To keep control of how it auto wraps I’d like to have it add a line break after every forth item.

For example currently a list of 8 items might display like this:

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6
7 | 8
```

Obviously where it wraps depends on the width of each items which can’t be a fixed width. I’d like it to display like this:

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4
5 | 6 | 7 | 8
```

Currently the scss is:

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    border-right: 2px $cuco-pink solid;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
    border-right: 0px $cuco-pink solid;
}
li:last-child {
    border-right: 0px $cuco-pink solid;
}
li:nth-child(4n+5) {
    clear: both;
}
```

After playing around with it all afternoon I can get to to wrap after every 4th item if I use float: left and display:inline BUT then can’t get it centred

OR I can get it centred by using float: none and display:inline-block BUT then can’t get it to wrap correctly.

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cucocreative/cvk15qj5/), once fixed I would then go onto make it responsive by altering the nth-child setting.

Comment: Should it *always* wrap every four items? What about smaller and larger screens? (This is why responsive grids were invented.)

Comment: Yes wraps every four items. The list is user entered and is amongst the standard WordPress content, ie <?php the_content(); ?> so I can't use what I'd normally us (Foundation6 Block Grid).

Comment: That's a tough one. Pseudo-element clearing doesn't seem to work. There are several solutions involving JavaScript on SO. If you're working in PHP you might just do it there. Add a CSS class to every 4th item.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a DIV, and then you can center the div: IE:

```
#ul-container {
 width: 300px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

the div was given the id of ul-container

Comment: and make sure all your li has their closing li. after running it in test with all closing tags. everything centered fine.

Comment: In my jsfiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/cucocreative/cvk15qj5/] they do have all their closing tags, but I can't get the list to wrap at every 4th item AND be centred.

Answer (score 0):

try to use display:flex; property for this purpose. and give width to li 25% (20% for 4 items);

```
ul { 
width: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

here is updated fiddle; hopefully it will help. https://jsfiddle.net/cvk15qj5/2/

Comment: Thanks, but the <li> can't have a fixed width, they need to be as big/small as their content is.

Comment: But the second row of the list is still left aligned and not centered and it no longer adds a break after the 4th item?

Comment: static way to add the break after every 4 items is to give width to them. if your contents are being generated dynamically, then you need to setup the loop.. in that loop you need to initiate a counter that will add a clearfix div after every 4 items. The way you are seeking that every 4 or 5th nth-child take clear:both; will not work .. as it will effect both top and bottom elements;

Comment: The list is user entered and is amongst the standard WordPress content, ie <?php the_content(); ?>